# iOS sending JSON array giving null data in Web API

Tags: c#, ios, json, rest

This is the POST Body iOS is sending me but when I debug in my code my parameter is getting null.

```
{
    OrderTable = 
    ({
        Name = 401;
        Status = add;
     },
     {
        Name = 101;
        Status = remove;
     });
}
```

Is this correct format  they are sending me,

My Service is accepting parameter like this

```
[{
"Name": "",
"Status": "add"
},
{
"Name": "",
"Status": "remove"
}]
```

Any way to accept this or fix this.

My Post method is like this

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostOrderTable(OrderTableCollection orderTableCollection)
{            
    this.orderService.AddTables(orderTableCollection);
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

and OrderTableCollection is like this

```
[XmlRoot("OrderTables")]
public class OrderTableCollection : Collection<OrderTable>
{

}
```

Comment: Show us code of the API which is accepting this info ?

Comment: public HttpResponseMessage PostOrderTable(OrderTableCollection orderTableCollection)
        {            
            this.orderService.AddTables(orderTableCollection);
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }